# Regd : Post api not working in Ionic 6 & unable to get response from server

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I want to implement post request in Ionic Application. My URL is  http://pridediesel.com/pridediesel/api/login?email=a@a.com&password=12,

Can anyone guide me reg the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

 sendPostRequest() {
    this.http.post("http://pridediesel.com/pridediesel/api/login?", {"email": "a@a.com","password":"12"})
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: i tried working with the answer you posted.Getting 405 error.Please guide.

Comment: 405 error means request not known by the server so its not client-side issue........